# Mapinfo Polygon to GeoJson for Google Map

Tags: google-maps, polygon, openstreetmap, mapbox, mapinfo

i want to ask how to export Mapinfo Polygon to GeoJson for Google Map or OpenStreetmap / MapBox, or maybe there is another way to do.

I have try export csv and tab but only point (latitude longitude) not the polygon

Thanks.

Comment: There may be possible answer for your question in GIS stackexchange. Here it is: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5315/converting-mapinfo-tab-to-geojson

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting your MapInfo Tab file into a MID/MIF file (using Table>Export in MapInfo). The MID/MIF format is plain text so you should then be able to parse these files to create a GeoJson though you will probably have to write the code for this yourself.